# Arduino LED blink 3 time without reasons

Tags: c, avr, atmega

I'm trying to program an ATmega328P microcontroller  (on a Az-delivery arduino card) directly with C-code.

When I ran a simple blink program in order to test compilation and communication between my computer and the board I had any problem to blink the build-in LED.

Bellow the code who perfectly work :

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void){
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB5);
    while(1){
        PORTB |= 1 << PORTB5;
        _delay_ms(500);//0.35
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB5);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

(hex file :

```
:10000000259A2D9A2FEF89E698E121508040904063
:10001000E1F700C000002D982FEF89E698E121500C
:0C00200080409040E1F700C00000EBCFF2
:00000001FF
```

)

The problem occurs when I start to wrote simple function. My LED blink rapidly three times before turn off during 1 second and it did it over and over again...

I tried to find out what is the problem. So in order to do this I remove everything line by line... And when I tried these two codes, the first one didn't anything but the second one has the strange behaviour explained previously.

Code who did what I want :

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void){
    while(1){}
}
```

(hex file :

```
:02000000FFCF30
:00000001FF
```

)

Code who flashing my LED three time again and again :
(Even with adding the line `DDRB |= (1 << DDB5);` for port initialisation just before the while loop)

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void setHigh_Led(void);

int main(void){
    
    while(1){
    }
}


void setHigh_Led(void){
}
```

(hex file

- with initialisation :

```
:060000000895259AFFCFD0
:00000001FF
```

- without initialisation :

```
:040000000895FFCF91
:00000001FF
```

)

The following code is closer to the original one and it turn on my LED but in the time who it should be off, it blink :

```
void setHigh_Led(void);

int main(void){    
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB5);
    while(1){
        setHigh_Led();
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB5);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}


void setHigh_Led(void){
    PORTB |= 1 << PORTB5;
}
```

(hex file :

```
:100000002D9A0895259A0E9400002FEF89E698E125
:10001000215080409040E1F700C000002D982FEF64
:1000200089E698E1215080409040E1F700C000004F
:02003000EACF15
:00000001FF
```

)

To beeing complete these are the scripts line I execute to compile and send my code to the card :

```
avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o blink/blink.o blink/blink.c
 avr-gcc -o blink/blink.bin blink/blink.o
 avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom blink/blink.bin blink/blink.hex
 avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P COM3 -b 115200 -U flash:w:blink.hex
```

Can you help me to understand what's happend ?

Comment: I use C... Can it be linked to my problem ?

Comment: Where are your `setup()` and `loop()` functions? Arduino isn't C. Are default functions being run? The two programs you show seem to be functionally identical. Neither has any funtionality.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes I know but I'm trying to use C code dirrectly and not the Arduino overlay.
This code work perfectly for example (the blink one) : ```#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void){
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB5);
    while(1){
        PORTB |= 1 << PORTB5;
        _delay_ms(500);//0.35
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB5);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}

Comment: Most likely boot loader is called and your program is not executed at all

Comment: Please don't post unreadable code in comments. You can edit the original post with more detail. And you should, because the post doesn't include any "blink" code.

Comment: @gulpr Oh ! But Why when I didn't implement any function it works so ?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes I'm sory it's edited

Comment: In the empty codes with seemingly random behaviour, you've not made any port initialisation. It's a bit strange, since output devices at startup are usually in a benign state, to prevent the accidental triggering of alarms, say. Are your LED's properly biased electrically? Or is there a hardware fault?

Comment: Yes the led is correctly wired, It's the built-in one so I cannot change it. (It's the Led L of the board).

After test, even with port initialization it had the same behaviour (I will edited my question with this information)

Comment: You added the `DDRB` port output configuration code, but no data was written.

Comment: An (somewhat educated) guess: did you consult Arduino manual? It sounds to me like the blinking pattern may be board communicating that a bad program was uploaded to flash (e.g., one without `setup()` and `loop()` functions, which may be expected by the firmware). I have no idea if Arduino actually requires the functions or if it uses the LED to signal its state, but it seems reasonable.

Comment: Publish hex file in your question

Comment: I edited my post by adding a code who is closer to the original one where I saw the error the first time.

Of course I can add hex file... But which can be useful ? All of them ?

Comment: I just added all hex files generated by avr-gcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am decompiled this

```
:060000000895259AFFCFD0
:00000001FF
```

as

```
00000000 <.sec1>:
   0:   08 95           ret
   2:   25 9a           sbi     0x04, 5 ; 4
   4:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2             ;  0x4
```

As you can see, it is only pure code that is in the source file. Since the function is empty, it is compiled only as a return instruction. However, since the function call is missing, stack overflow occurs.

You don't have the correct linking where the -mmcu=atmega328p option is missing.
Without -mmcu avr-gcc doesn't link proper crt.o, so main is not called.

Change command

```
 avr-gcc -o blink/blink.bin blink/blink.o
```

to

```
 avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p -o blink/blink.bin blink/blink.o
```

Then you get the correct code where the main function is called correctly